# flutter broken codes after unexpected computer shut off

Tags: flutter, android-studio, null, windows-10, shutdown

I am new to flutter and trying to learn.
While working on a flutter project in Android Studio, my computer suddenly shut down (my system is Windows 10, it crashed giving a blue screen error). when i open android studio again my codes have been changed like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ZLe.jpg). How can I recover my codes. Thanks for the help...

The last line was full of `NULLNULLNULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that nothing can be done in such a situation, for these purposes there are backup copies.

Comment: that is why git is necessary

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can do anything about this but you can backup your code on [enter link description here](https://github.com/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When I opened my code files which have dart extension in directory of C:\Users\username \AndroidStudioProjects\projectname\lib... with notepad , I saw that my codes had not changed actually. So I can recover my original codes from here.
but it is still unrecognized issue for me why android studio shows my codes strangely...